# All feature classes are not shown when creating new topology in ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, topology, arccatalog

I am generally a self taught GIS guy and I typically figure things out with extensive research. I have been reading through the ArcGIS Help online, specifically on [Creating A Topology](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/topologies/creating-a-topology.htm). The link provides a step by step process on creating the a new topology.

I have a variety of layers related to a sewer system and I would like to create a topology so that I can ensure everything is connected appropriately prior to setting up a geometric network. The process I have followed in ArcCatalog is as follows:

1. Right click the relationship class in the geodatabase, select New, then select Topology.
2. Click next, in the dialogue that pops up I set the name of the topology and the cluster tolerance. Click next.
3. On the next screen I have to select the feature classes that will participate in the topology. Unfortunately all the feature classes listed and selectable are not all those that are in the relationship class of the geodatabase. See the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot of geodatabase relationship class and the new topology dialogue box]

Turns out that only one (1) of the features classes that would be part of the new topology is selectable. I need many of the others that are not listed and selectable in the dialogue box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a existing geometric network that is old and incorrect associated with the geodatabase. The feature classes that were associated with the network would could not be added to another topological network.